What prevents SSH authentication from Succeeding with Cloud-init Installation
Despite following the example config provided in the cloud-init documentation example-config on how to include users and groups, once the server is initialized, ssh key authentication fails with the following error Permission denied (publickey).
The provided "user-data" file includes the public key associated with the private key on my local system, the ssh_deletekey property is set to false, and the permissions of the private key on my system are set properly with chmod 600.
What else would prevent ssh authentication from succeeding?
#cloud-config

# This is the user-data configuration file for cloud-init. By default this sets
# up an initial user called "ubuntu" with password "ubuntu", which must be
# changed at first login. However, many additional actions can be initiated on
# first boot from this file. The cloud-init documentation has more details:
#
# https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/
#
# Please note that the YAML format employed by this file is sensitive to
# differences in whitespace; if you are editing this file in an editor (like
# Notepad) which uses literal tabs, take care to only use spaces for
# indentation. See the following link for more details:
#
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML
#
# Some additional examples are provided in comments below the default
# configuration.


## Set the system's hostname. Please note that, unless you have a local DNS
## setup where the hostname is derived from DHCP requests (as with dnsmasq),
## setting the hostname here will not make the machine reachable by this name.
## You may also wish to install avahi-daemon (see the "packages:" key below)
## to make your machine reachable by the .local domain
hostname: teem

## Set up the keyboard layout. See localectl(1), in particular the various
## list-x11-* sub-commands, to determine the available models, layouts,
## variants, and options
keyboard:
  model: pc105
  layout: us
#  variant:
#  options: ctrl:nocaps

# Controls password authentication with the SSH daemon; the default here
# prevents logging into SSH with a password. Changing this is a security risk
# and you should at the very least ensure a different default password is
# specified above
ssh_pwauth: false

## On first boot, use ssh-import-id to give the specific users SSH access to
## the default user
#ssh_import_id:
#- lp:my_launchpad_username
#- gh:my_github_username

## Add users and groups to the system, and import keys with the ssh-import-id
## utility
groups:
  - admingroup: [root, sys]

users:
  - default
  - name: admin
    gecos: Cedric Sullivan
    groups:
      - users
      - sudo
      - admin
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock_passwd: true
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - "ssh-rsa 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 user@example"

ssh_deletekeys: false
## Update apt database and upgrade packages on first boot
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

## Install additional packages on first boot
packages:
  - avahi-daemon
#- rng-tools
#- python3-gpiozero
#- [python3-serial, 3.5-1]

## Write arbitrary files to the file-system (including binaries!)
#write_files:
#- path: /etc/default/console-setup
#  content: |
#    # Consult the console-setup(5) manual page.
#    ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
#    CHARMAP="UTF-8"
#    VIDEOMODE=
#    FONT="Lat15-Terminus18x10.psf.gz"
#    FONTFACE=
#    FONTSIZE=
#    CODESET="Lat15"
#  permissions: '0644'
#  owner: root:root
#- encoding: gzip
#  path: /root/Makefile
#  content: !!binary |
#    H4sICF2DTWIAA01ha2VmaWxlAFNWCM8syVBILMjPyU/PTC1WKMlXiPB2dlFQNjSx5MpNteLi
#    dLDiSoRQxYl5KeWZyRkgXrSCkoqKRmaKgm6pppKCbmqhgoFCrIKamkK1QmpyRr6Ckn92YqWS
#    NdC80uQMBZhOa4VahZoaqIrwjMQSewXfxOxUhcwShcr80qLi1Jw0RSUuAIYfEJmVAAAA
#  owner: root:root
#  permissions: '0644'

## Run arbitrary commands at rc.local like time
#runcmd:
#- [ ls, -l, / ]
#- [ sh, -xc, "echo $(date) ': hello world!'" ]
#- [ wget, "http://ubuntu.com", -O, /run/mydir/index.html ]

Here's the Output from ssh admin@serverIP -i key_file -v
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/airfield/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to teem.local [192.168.1.49] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file teem_ssh type 0
debug1: identity file teem_ssh-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to teem.local:22 as 'admin'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/airfield/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+R0YqlFfhiP/FqfKcICPcCIVDTQyVoRBanyoCrVlhUs
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/airfield/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'teem.local' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/airfield/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: teem_ssh RSA SHA256:haPv+kMHgxyjbCKIjSZTaIgSIetJShdwLVWfMKlZZkg explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: ping@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: teem_ssh RSA SHA256:haPv+kMHgxyjbCKIjSZTaIgSIetJShdwLVWfMKlZZkg explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
admin@teem.local: Permission denied (publickey).


ssh -v will tell you more. Please [edit] your Question, and use the formatting tools. Do not use Add Comment.

If you can access the server in some other way, then the next thing to do is check the cloud init logs ( /var/log/cloud-init*.log) and ssh logs (journalctl -u ssh).

Upon further inspection of the logs after following the suggestion left by muru in their comment, I found this error KeyError: 'getpwnam(): name not found in the /var/log/cloud-init*.log of the server, indicating that the credentials for the user couldn't be authenticated because the user didn't exist! Apparently user creation failed because the user couldn't be added to the admin group. Once I removed admin from the list of groups of the user, I was able to successfully ssh into the server using the key.
users:
  - default
  - name: admin
    gecos: Cedric Sullivan
    groups:
      - users
      - sudo
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock_passwd: true
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - "ssh-rsa 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 user@example"


